# How can I navigate to the mysite of someone else?

Tags: mysite

I am using sp 2013. When I click in the top navigation bar on "Sites" I go to mysite. this is the url of mysite:

> http://mijn.mycompany.nl/persoonlijk/johndoe/Social/Sites.aspx#IsEditing_WPQ4=1

When I would like to go to the mysite of my colleage I replace the username in the url, for example:

> http://mijn.mycompany.nl/persoonlijk/frankjackson/Social/Sites.aspx#IsEditing_WPQ4=1

I think there other ways to navigate to the mysite of someone else. Does someone know how?

Comment: There are variety of ways to go to other's profile. It depends how you want it? Would you want to have some JSOM code? or do you want to list all users some where on the page? Can you throw some more light on your question please. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use People Search. And then click on the User Name which takes you to that Users Profile.

Also if you see the user name in Say any list or other places, you can click on the link that will take you to the users profile.

Comment: I do not want to go to the myprofile page, I want to go to the mysite page. See url above.

Comment: You can do search term `personal username`.. And use the first link.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with search term personal username?

Comment: in the search box type `personal` then put a space than type username whose mysite you want to find

Comment: I enter in the search box "personal johndoe" with no results. I remove the word personal and I got 1 result. All hyperlinks on this result are going to the myprofile and not to the mysite.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse MySite in couple of ways but keep in mind you will get only the information which User Shared or common information from profile.

- you can search the User from people Search or go to your own newsfeed check for orgnization chart.
- Once you click on the user's profile link it will bring the user's profile page.
- on this page left handside, you will see the information which user allow to see other.
- If you have permision on user's one drive then you will see document link.otherwise you will see the **About user** and **People**.

This thing is change from 2010.